How many photons does an X-ray tube emit?
I want to estimate the number of photons emitted by an X-ray tube under the following assumptions:

The tube is a tungsten tube at 60 kV, 1 mA, no inherent filtration.
The X-ray tube converts roughly 1% of it's power to X-rays (the rest being dissipated as heat).
The radiation is monochromatic at 35 keV (~ mean energy of tungsten spectrum at 60kVp).
All produced X-rays are actually emitted (no scatter, no collimation etc.).

My calculation is as follows:
$P_{\mathrm{Tube}} = U*I = 60~$kV$ * 1~$mA$~= 60~$W
$P_{\mathrm{X-ray}} = 0.01 * 60\mathrm{W}~= 0.6~$W
$N_{\mathrm{photons/s}} = 0.6\mathrm{W} \cdot 6.241\cdot 10^{15}\frac{\mathrm{keV}}{\mathrm{Ws}}/35 \mathrm{keV} = 1.07 \cdot 10^{14}\frac{\mathrm{Photons}}{\mathrm{s}} $
Is that at least roughly correct?

Seems like a reasonable estimate.
